# Specifying values in enumeration: Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Easy to drop an enumeration object into a class diagram, but they've changed how you actually specify the values. Where is that?

Comment: so far, I'm putting them in Constraints and using Compartment Visibility to display them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values in an Enumeration can be added in the **Features** window.

The easiest way to make the Features window appear is to select your enumeration in a diagram and press **F9**
[image]
Enumeration values are added in the **Attributes** tab of the features window.

Comment: Depending on which version of EA you use. They shift those properties to and fro.

Comment: Thanks.  Windows: & EA 15.2 fn+F9
So maybe the real question is: Where does Sparx keep the decoder ring for when they shift things to and fro?

Comment: I don't know the exact location, but I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in Mordor. I tried walking there once, but...